# Click handler for each button incorrectly returns the last button of a set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a click handler to each button that is generated in a loop and inserted into an array.

However, clicking a button always outputs the last button of each row of buttons and not the specific button itself.

My code is rather verbose, but we only need to be looking at the `time.push()` part and the click handler setup. Everything else is just *setup*.

```
import React from 'react';

import { friendlyTimeSlot, scopedTimeslots } from '../../utilities/helpers';

class TimeSlotStack extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      times: undefined
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.updatePropsAndState(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.updatePropsAndState(nextProps);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  updatePropsAndState(props) {
    const time = [];
    let matchedTimeSlots;

    if (props.promotionId) {
      matchedTimeSlots = props.timeSlots.filter(timeSlot => {
        const timeSlotsIds = timeSlot.AvailablePromotions.map(p => p.Id);
        if (timeSlotsIds.includes(props.promotionId)) {
          return timeSlot;
        }
        return false;
      });
    } else {
      matchedTimeSlots = props.timeSlots.filter(timeSlot => timeSlot.HasStandardAvailability);
    }

    const scopedTimes = scopedTimeslots(matchedTimeSlots, props.preferredTimeSlot);

    scopedTimes.forEach((item, i) => {
      const friendlyTime = friendlyTimeSlot(item.TimeSlot, true);
      const leaveTimeRequired = item.IsLeaveTimeRequired;

      let itemPromo;
      let leaveTime;
      let itemPrice;

      if (props.promotionId) {
        itemPromo = item.AvailablePromotions.find(ourItem => ourItem.Id === props.promotionId);
        leaveTime = itemPromo.LeaveTime || item.LeaveTime;
        itemPrice = (itemPromo.BasePrice > 0) ? `£${itemPromo.BasePrice}` : '';
      } else {
        leaveTime = item.LeaveTime;
      }

      time.push(
        <button
          className="btn btn-default"
          type="button"
          onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e)}
          ref={input => {
            this.button = input;
          }}
          key={i}
          data-time={friendlyTime}
          data-leave-time-required={leaveTimeRequired}
          data-leave-time={leaveTime.slice(0, -3)}
          data-promotion-id={props.promotionId}
        >
          {friendlyTimeSlot(item.TimeSlot)}<br />{itemPrice}
        </button>
      );
    });

    this.setState({
      times: time
    });
  }

  clickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.button.dataset);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.times && this.props.name && this.props.description) {
      return (
        <div className="panel panel-default">
          <div className="panel-heading">
            <h3 className="panel-title">{this.props.name}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="panel-body">
            <p>{this.props.description}</p>
            {this.state.times}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <p>No times available.</p>
    );
  }

}

TimeSlotStack.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  timeSlots: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  preferredTimeSlot: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  promotionId: React.PropTypes.number
};

export default TimeSlotStack;
```

When I then click a button, I always get the last button from each list. Hopefully the screenshot below will help make this clearer:

[image]

The log above comes from:

```
clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.button.dataset);
}
```

...but was generated by clicking the first buttons of each row. You can see that it always outputs the last only.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? This is my first React project and it's gotten me all flustered. Please let me know if I'm doing something that's not the *React way* that could be causing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `button` variable, `this` in this context is a reference to a `TimeSlotStack` instance. To do what you want you need to maintain a list of buttons, for instance.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  this.buttons = [];
  this.state = {
    times: undefined
  };
}

....
// using a IFE so `clickHandler` is called with the correct index
((idx) => {
  time.push(
    <button
      className="btn btn-default"
      type="button"
      onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e, idx)}
      ref={button => {
        this.buttons.push(button);
      }}
      key={idx}
      data-time={friendlyTime}
      data-leave-time-required={leaveTimeRequired}
      data-leave-time={leaveTime.slice(0, -3)}
      data-promotion-id={props.promotionId}
    >
      {friendlyTimeSlot(item.TimeSlot)}<br />{itemPrice}
    </button>
  );
})(i);
....

clickHandler(e, i) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.buttons[i].dataset);
}
```

Comment: I get an error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" - I guess because you're doing this.buttons.push(button); in the ref, but what is buttons? A new array I need to create?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add this to the answer, I'll edit

Comment: Nice, thanks! Any reason to use this.buttons on the constructor and not hold these in this.state.buttons ?

Comment: Adding them to the state will probably cause an infinite loop. Changing the state causes a component to rerender, and after the component is mounted into the DOM the `ref` callback is called, can you see the problem? You will trigger to rerender every time the component finishes rendering. You can read more here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html